# How to merge android repo branch off old release to new release master?

Tags: android, git, build, android-source, repository

We have an android platform repo branch worked on by a vendor. Lets say it is vendor-branch. It is based off release 1.0. The vendor-branch changes were never committed to release 1.0.

Now we are working on release 3.0. But I want to start where the vendor left off in vendor-branch and merge with release 3.0 workspace.

How do I do that with android repo tool?

I have done repo init with 3.0 followed by repo sync. I am looking for a way to merge vendor-branch changes onto 3.0 version in my workspace.

What is the right repo command for this?

Is there a web page that explains different sub commands of repo?

Thanks
Videoguy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [documentation page for repo](http://source.android.com/source/using-repo.html). I've never used repo myself but it appears to be an abstraction over some git commands written with python. The [upload](http://source.android.com/source/using-repo.html#upload) command seems promising.

Failing that you can always use git. You should be able to perform a [three way merge](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging) of your branch to master and sync that.

Answer (score 1):

The webpage that explains different repo commands is [here](http://source.android.com/source/using-repo.html). Repo command is just a number of Python scripts over git commands. These scripts you can find in your AOSP folder under the following path: `.repo/repo/subcmds`

I guess in your case you have to use `repo forall` with command to merge all git subprojects.